# Split doesn't work with json_encode in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, split, json

I have an array in php like this:

```
$array_php = (1,2,3,4,5);
```

In JavaScript I do:

```
var obj = <?php echo json_encode($array_php); ?>;
```

If I do **alert(obj);** I get the content well without problems: 1,2,3,4,5

If I do:

```
var elem = obj.split(',');
```

This fail. If I do alert(elem[1]) for example I don't get anything. And the line var elem = ... fails.

If I create the array without json_enconde works fine, but I need access to this object.

What can I do?
Thanks!

Comment: You probably need to do something like: `var obj = JSON.parse(<?php echo json_encode($array_php); ?>);`.

Comment: Yeah. I agree. So, then you can iterate over `obj` using `arr = $.pareseJSON(obj)`, accessing each object in a `for` loop!

Comment: @Andy: Nope. JSON is a subset of JavaScript literal notation, so if you're dropping it into JavaScript source, the JavaScript parser can handle it directly. (In fact, if you did what's in your comment, you'd get a parsing error, because it would become `JSON.parse([1,2,3,4,5])` which triggers `toString` on the array giving us `JSON.parse("1,2,3,4,5")`, which fails because `"1,2,3,4,5"` is invalid JSON.)

Comment: @Andy:No you don't need to parse again on JS. It will get already JSON object at JS when you use json_encode()

Comment: I learn something new every day.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder thanks, so how can I do to get a normal javascript array from php array?

Comment: @SohilDesai: No, it *won't* be a "JSON object". JSON is a textual notation. It will be a JavaScript object (or array) literal in the JavaScript source code, and a JavaScript object in memory.

Comment: @user3396420: [Niet's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22860074/157247) is correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`alert(obj)` converts the array to a string. Array-to-string conversion in JavaScript is essentially done with `this.join(",")` (not exactly, but close enough).

You don't have to do anything to `obj` to make it an array, it *is* an array! So just access `alert(obj[1])` and you'll get `2`.

Answer (score 1):

That's not a PHP array. Do you mean `array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);`?

Using `json_encode` like this creates a string with an JavaScript object or array literal, but since you are outputsing it directly into JavaScript, it's not a string, but allready an array in JavaScript. Look at the generated source code. It will be:

```
var obj = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
```

not

```
var obj = "[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]";
```

and also not

```
var obj = "1, 2, 3, 4, 5";
```

So you don't need to split it (there is no string to split). Just access the object (or in this case array) directly:

```
alert(obj[0]); // Shows 1
```

Hint: Don't use `alert()` for debuggging. Use `console.log()` instead and look at the console. There it's easier to see that it's an array and not a string.

Comment: *"Hint: Don't use alert() for debuggging. Use console.log() instead...* Hint: Don't use `console.log` for debugging. Use a *debugger* for debugging. There's one built into your browser, which lets you single-step through the code, inspect variables, etc. :-) +1 for excellent info (including that hint).